# Installation DVC on MinIO storage

Tags: python, minio, dvc

Does anybody install DVC on MinIO storage?

I have read [docs](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/remote/modify#available-parameters-per-storage-type) but not all clear for me.

Which command should I use for setup MinIO storage with this entrance parameters:

storage url: https://minio.mysite.com/minio/bucket-name/
login: my_login
password: my_password

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Install**

I usually use it as a Python package, in this case you need to install:

```bash
pip install "dvc[s3]"
```

**Setup remote**

By default DVC supports AWS S3 storage and it works fine.
It also supports "S3-compatible storage", and MinIO in particular. In this case you have a **bucket** - a directory on a MinIO server where actual data is stored (it is similar to an AWS bucket). DVC uses AWS CLI to authenticate with AWS and in case of MinIO you need to pass credentials to `dvc` (not to the `minio` package).

The commands to setup MinIO as your DVC remote:

```bash
# setup default remote (change "bucket-name" to your minio backet name)
dvc remote add -d minio s3://bucket-name -f

# add information about storage url (where "https://minio.mysite.com" is your MinIO url)
dvc remote modify minio endpointurl https://minio.mysite.com

#  add MinIO credentials (e.g. from env. variables)
dvc remote modify minio access_key_id my_login
dvc remote modify minio secret_access_key my_password
```

**If you move from old remote**, use the following commands to move your data:

Before setup (download old remote cache to the local machine - note it may take a long time):

```bash
dvc pull -r <old_remote_name> --all-commits --all-tags --all-branches
```

After setup (upload all local cache data to a new remote):

```bash
dvc push -r <new_remote_name> --all-commits --all-tags --all-branches
```

Comment: Doy you know how to issue commands like dvc list-/import- when using such s3 compatible backends? (Credentials wise I mean)

Comment: Hello! Don't you know why I can get
WARNING: failed to collect '<commit_hash>', skipping
after doing dvc push (last command)?

Answer (score 0):

May be useful: I have self-hosted MinIO and when i'd tried to push I had an error `ERROR: unexpected error - [Errno 22] Bad Request: An error occurred (400) when calling the HeadObject operation: Bad Request`

The solution is to add `use_ssl = False` to my dvc config file, so my config file looks like

```
[core]
    remote = minio
    autostage = true
['remote "minio"']
    url = s3://tags-by-review/DVC
    endpointurl = http://...:9000/
    version_aware = true
    use_ssl = False
```